# What happens to Fluffy, after the events of Philosopher's Stone?

Tags: harry-potter

We know that Fluffy helped in protecting the Sorcerer's stone in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*. Does anyone know what happened to Fluffy after that?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Acc. to [HP Lexicon](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/bestiary/beasts.html), JK Rowling answered this herself in a BBC interview on the Blue Peter TV show on BBC on March 12, 2001.

> Child: What happened to Fluffy...?
>
> JKR: I love attentive readers...you tend to find at Hogwarts that anything that's dangerous ends up in the forest ... so that's where Fluffy was released, so he's roaming round in the forest...

Comment: I somehow can't imagine poor little Fluffly in the forest - I'm sure Hagrid must visit him (her?) sometimes

Answer (score 45):

In an interview in 2001, she gave an initial answer:

> **What happened to Fluffy?**
>
> You tend to find at Hogwarts that, erm, anything that's dangerous ends up in the forest, so that's where Fluffy was released, so he's roaming round in the forest.
>
> — [Interview transcript from *Blue Peter* (March 2001)](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/0301-bluepeter.htm)

She later claimed on Twitter that he was actually sent back to Greece:

> **What happened to Fluffy after he was released into the forest? I hope he returned to Hogwarts for the battle!**
>
> He was repatriated to Greece. Dumbledore liked to put Hagrid's more foolish acquisitions back where they belong – not the forest.
>
> — [*@JKRowling on Twitter* (Feb 2015)](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/563634348524843008)

The most likely interpretation is that he was initially sent into the Forest, but Dumbledore later thought better of this idea (probably after Hagrid had stopped visiting Fluffy), and that was when he had him deported.

Comment: Interesting. And since the common acceptance is that the more recent word of god answer is the more canonical, that makes this the right answer.

Answer (score 10):

[Accio Quote](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/0301-bluepeter.htm) (which currently experiences technical difficulties, so I went by [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3akdXrh56DJDUJ%3awww.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/0301-bluepeter.htm+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)) "Interview transcript (partial), Blue Peter (cBBC), 12 March, 2001"

> JKR: ... erm, you tend to find at Hogwarts that, erm, anything that's dangerous ends up in the forest ... so that's where Fluffy was released, so he's roaming round in the forest ...

Comment: Added that reference 2 minutes before you did. :)

Comment: @ykombinator - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q53rpoyfRx8 :)

Answer (score 2):

From [harrypotter.wikia.com](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Fluffy)

> After Fluffy's duties were done, and the Stone was destroyed, Hagrid
>   set Fluffy free in the Forbidden Forest. Presumably, he is still
>   there.